# Finding the minimum of $|S_1-S_2|+|S_3-S_4|+|S_5-S_6|+|S_7-S_8|$ where $S$ is a sum of $x,y$, and $z$.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, absolute-value

Consider $24$ positive numbers; $x_1, \dots, x_8,y_1, \dots, y_8,z_1, \dots, z_8$.

Let

$$M=|\text{sum of }(\text{one }x, \text{one }y, \text{one }z)-\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }x,\text{different }z)|$$

$$+|\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)-\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)|$$

$$+|\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)-\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)|$$

$$+|\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)-\text{sum of }(\text{different }x,\text{different }y,\text{different }z)|$$

Clarification: the word "different" indicates that any of the $24$ numbers must be used (exactly) one time.

How can I find the minimum possible value of $M$ (without a software)?

---

Example:

[image]

With the help of EXCEL, I found that

$$M=|(x_2+y_1+z_1)-(x_1+y_5+z_3)|$$

$$+|(x_3+y_3+z_5)-(x_5+y_8+z_2)|$$

$$+|(x_4+y_7+z_7)-(x_7+y_4+z_8)|$$

$$+|(x_8+y_2+z_4)-(x_6+y_6+z_6)|=1.50$$

is the minimum possible value of $M$.

I am not sure if this answer is correct or not. I just included this example so that my problem will be understood.

What I did using EXCEL;

I found the $512$ possible sums, that is, I found

$x_1+y_1+z_1,x_1+y_1+z_2, \dots, x_1+y_1+z_8,x_2+y_2+z_1,x_2+y_2+z_2, \dots, x_2,y_2,z_8, \dots, x_8+y_8,z_1, x_8+y_8+z_2, \dots, x_8+y_8+z_8$

then I paired them.

---

If there is any good trick without using software, it would be great.

Comment: @achillehui it is mentioned in the post that any of the $24$ numbers must be used exactly one time. What can you understand from this dear? Sorry for my English, it is weak.

Comment: I think it took a long time to solve this problem. I am not sure if it is possible without finding the $512$ possibilities.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any trick, but I used integer linear programming to find that the minimum is $0$:
\begin{align}
|21.00 + 11.70 +  3.60 -18.00 -10.80 -7.50| &= 0 \\
|15.45 +  9.90 + 12.15 -21.45 -12.00 -4.05| &= 0 \\
|18.30 + 10.35 +  6.45 -13.35 -16.80 -4.95| &= 0 \\
|14.25 + 14.70 +  9.45 -19.05 -12.00 -7.35| &= 0 
\end{align}

For $i\in I:=\{1,\dots,8\}$ and $j\in J:=\{1,\dots,3\}$, let $a_{i,j}$ be the entry in row $i$ and column $j$.  Let $G:=\{1,\dots,4\}$ be the groups.  Let binary decision variables $p_{i,j,g}$ and $n_{i,j,g}$ indicate whether entry $(i,j)$ appears in group $g$ with a positive sign or negative sign, respectively.  The problem is to minimize $$\sum_{g \in G} \left|\sum_{i\in I} \sum_{j\in J} a_{i,j} (p_{i,j,g} - n_{i,j,g})\right|$$ subject to linear constraints:
\begin{align}
\sum_{g \in G} (p_{i,j,g} + n_{i,j,g}) &= 1 &&\text{for $i\in I$ and $j \in J$} \tag1 \\
\sum_{i \in I} p_{i,j,g} &= 1 &&\text{for $j \in J$ and $g \in G$} \tag2 \\
\sum_{i \in I} n_{i,j,g} &= 1 &&\text{for $j \in J$ and $g \in G$} \tag3
\end{align}

Constraint $(1)$ assigns each entry to exactly one group.
Constraint $(2)$ assigns one positive entry per column and group.
Constraint $(3)$ assigns one negative entry per column and group.

The absolute value objective can be linearized in the standard way.

Comment: If you claimed that the minimum is some positive quantity, then I might ask you to prove that this is the minimum. But since the sum of arbitrary absolute values can have zero as the minimum, then your answer is correct about the minimum, and the verification you provided is really nice. (+1) for the answer. Still I am looking for a mathematical way (without software). It would be appreciated if you share the code, I may be able to get an idea to solve this problem. Thanks.